# SetInterval chamando função apenas uma vez?

Tags: javascript

Quero que as divs se locomovam -50px para a esquerda a cada 03 segundos.Usei setInterval mas ele só executa a função apenas uma vez.

```js
setInterval(function(){ document.querySelector('.filho').classList.add("ativado");
 }, 3000);
```

```css
<style>
    body{

padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
    .pai{
border:solid 1px black;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}

    #divs1{
padding: 100px;
background: pink;
transition: .5s;

}    #divs2{
padding: 100px;
background: green;
transition: .5s;

}    #divs3{
padding: 100px;
background: red;
transition: .9s;

}
    .ativado{
margin-left: -50px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
<body>

  <div class="pai">

   <div class="filho" id="divs1"></div>
   <div class="filho" id="divs2"></div>
   <div class="filho" id="divs3"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> SetInterval chamando função apenas uma vez?

A função, na verdade **está sendo chamada corretamente a cada 3 segundos**. O problema é que o seu `setInterval` simplesmente adiciona a classe `ativado` sempre que é executado a cada 3 segundos. Isso não irá alterar a posição depois da primeira vez, já que a classe já foi adicionada na execução anterior, não fazendo diferença nas chamadas seguintes.

O que você precisa fazer é algo que adicione mais `50px` a cada execução.

---

Fiz um exemplo para você tomar como base:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#el')
let current = 0

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  // Define o valor de "margin-top" como o valor anterior mais 10.
  // Note que temos que adicionar "px" após o valor calculado.
  el.style.setProperty('margin-top', `${current += 10}px`)
  console.log(`Valor atual: ${current}px`)
  
  // Caso o valor seja maior que 500, pare o intervalo:
  if (current >= 150) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    console.log('Intervalo interrompido! Fim.')
  }
}, 500)
```

```html
<div id="el">Olá!</div>
```

---

### Código final:

Desse modo, você precisa basicamente disso:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.filho')
let current = 0

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  el.style.setProperty('margin-left', `${current -= 50}px`)
  
  // Caso o valor seja maior que 500, pare o intervalo.
  // Você pode remover essa parte se desejar.
  if (current >= 750) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    console.log('Intervalo interrompido! Fim.')
  }
}, 3000)
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.pai {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#divs1 {
  padding: 100px;
  background: pink;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#divs2 {
  padding: 100px;
  background: green;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#divs3 {
  padding: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pai">
      <div class="filho" id="divs1"></div>
      <div class="filho" id="divs2"></div>
      <div class="filho" id="divs3"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade a funcao esta correta, adicionei um console.log dentro do setInterval, pode ver que o log aparece varias vezes.

O problema e que voce esta simplesmente adicionando uma classe no elemento, o efeito do css nao é incremental, pode ter a classe `ativado` no elemento quantas vezes quiser e o `margin-left` vai ser sempre -50

o que precisa fazer é ir incrementando o valor.

```js
var margin = 0
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('fui chamado')
  margin -= 50
  document.querySelector('.filho').style.marginLeft = margin+'px'
}, 3000);
```

```css
<style>
    body{

padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
    .pai{
border:solid 1px black;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}

    #divs1{
padding: 100px;
background: pink;
transition: .5s;

}    #divs2{
padding: 100px;
background: green;
transition: .5s;

}    #divs3{
padding: 100px;
background: red;
transition: .9s;

}
    .ativado{
margin-left: -50px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
<body>

  <div class="pai">

   <div class="filho" id="divs1"></div>
   <div class="filho" id="divs2"></div>
   <div class="filho" id="divs3"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema e que a cada intervalo você esta setando o marginLeft a -50px, por isso ele fica parado depois das outras repetições, você precisa decrementar esse valor a cada intervalo.

```
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("filho")[0];
var margin = parseInt(obj.style.margin-left, 10);
obj.style.marginLeft = (margin - 50) + "px";
```

Insira isso no seu setInterval, deve resolver seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

O código está executando o que você pediu pra fazer, adicionar uma classe a um elemento, porém isso não faz com que os estilos CSS acumule, ou seja, dois elementos quaisquer, um com uma classe `ativado` e o outro com duas classes `ativado` são iguais (tem o mesmo estilo).

O que precisa fazer é incrementar a margem, por exemplo:

```
setInterval(function(){
    const style = document.querySelector('.filho').style;
    style.marginLeft = `${Number.parseInt(style.marginLeft.replace('px', '')) - 50}px`
}, 3000);
```